# Installing MacTeX, multiple user accounts

Tags: mactex

A question, before I start to install MacTeX (on OSX 10.8.5):

I have two different acoounts on my Mac: One for admin purposes only, and another one - which has no admin privileges - for the actual work.

As far as I understand, I should install MacTeX using the admin account, but I will be able to use it from the non-admin account (or any other user account on the machine). Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes it's correct.

Answer (score 6):

MacTeX installs a file in `/etc/paths.d`, precisely `/etc/paths.d/TeX`; such a file contains a single line

```
/usr/texbin
```

This means that the default `PATH` environment variable will contain (actually start with) `/usr/texbin` for *all users*.

Besides doing this, MacTeX also creates a symbolic link `/usr/texbin` that points to

```
../Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin
```

This is another symbolic link, which can be managed by the TeX Distribution control panel. This starts to seem complicated (and it is), but to keep things short, this further link points to

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

(or `universal-darwin`, depending on the version of Mac OS X). So the OS is able to find the required binaries when requested to and this holds for *every* user. Of course, only an Administrator account should run TeX Live Utility for updating the distribution.

Things can go wrong only if users have something in their `.profile` that directly set the value of `PATH`, which is however *A Bad Thing*.